# How to group names which are dependent on other columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like below.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
  CustId INT ,
  CustName VARCHAR(100) ,
  CustHeading VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO #Test

SELECT '1','john carroll','Heading 1'
UNION ALL
SELECT '1','john carroll','Heading 2' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2','john c','Heading 1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2','john c','Heading 2' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2','john c','Heading 3' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '3','john lynch','Heading 1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '4','john carroll lynch','Heading 1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '4','john carroll lynch','Heading 4' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '4','john carroll lynch','Heading 5' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '5','john c lynch','Heading 1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '5','john c lynch','Heading 3' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '6','john c l','Heading 11' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '6','john c l','Heading 12' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '7','john c ln','Heading 1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '7','john c ln','Heading 2' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2','john c','Heading 11' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2','john c','Heading 12'
```

In this, we need to group the customers who are having atleast **two** matching headings among them.

For example,custID :: 1,2 and 7 are having **two** matching CustHeading :: **Header 1 and Header 2**, so they are grouped.CustID :: 2 and 5 having **two** matching CustHeading :: **Header 1 and Header 3**,they also can be grouped. Please let me know how to achieve this

**without using WHILE loop**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As posted your question doesn't make much sense. Can you create a sql fiddle?

Comment: Decide your database first. `MySql` or `Sql Server` or `PostgreSql`?

Comment: please paste data as text that can be copy pasted, it makes it easier for users to replicate your data, write queries and provide answers.

Comment: And as I see `CustID = 1` have 5 matching headings where CustID in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. So how they grouping? All of them have the same headers, so how to group them correctly?

Comment: i want it in sql server script.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN c.num = 1 THEN a.CustId
         ELSE a.[_CustId]
    END ,
    CASE WHEN c.num = 1 THEN a.CustName
         ELSE a.[_CustName]
    END ,
    'M' + CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY mx, mn ) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS gr_nbr
FROM
    (
      SELECT
        a.CustId ,
        a.CustName ,
        c.CustId _CustId ,
        c.CustName _CustName,
        MAX(a.CustHeading) mx,
        MIN(a.CustHeading) mn
      FROM
        #Test a
        JOIN #Test c ON c.CustHeading = a.CustHeading
                     AND c.CustId > a.CustId
      GROUP BY
        a.CustId ,
        a.CustName ,
        c.CustId ,
        c.CustName
      HAVING
        MAX(a.CustHeading) <> MIN(a.CustHeading)
    ) a
    JOIN #Test b ON b.CustId = a.[_CustId]
    CROSS JOIN (
                 SELECT
                    1 num
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT
                    2 num
               ) AS c
ORDER BY
    3 ,
    1
```

Comment: this is not the resultset which i expected.

Comment: Did you add expected results after my answer?

Comment: Check now. I even added 1 more record to have 3 guys in the same group.

Comment: Check question, i have added expected resultset if two more records are added into the list.

Comment: and why is there 3rd group? 3 guys have the same headers. Why 2 of them are in the separate group?

Comment: Groups numbering does not match, but the result is as expected

Comment: yes.. thank you.. its indeed showing the same resultset as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my brain is not working today. I'm sure there is a simpler way to do this but I can think right now. This seems to work fine for me. Let me know if it needs any changes.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
  CustId INT ,
  CustName VARCHAR(100) ,
  CustHeading VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO #Test

SELECT '1','john carroll','Heading 1'
UNION ALL
SELECT '1','john carroll','Heading 2' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2','john c','Heading 1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2','john c','Heading 2' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2','john c','Heading 3' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '3','john lynch','Heading 1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '4','john carroll lynch','Heading 1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '4','john carroll lynch','Heading 4' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '4','john carroll lynch','Heading 5' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '5','john c lynch','Heading 1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '5','john c lynch','Heading 3' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '6','john c l','Heading 11' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '6','john c l','Heading 12' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '7','john c ln','Heading 1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '7','john c ln','Heading 2' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2','john c','Heading 11' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2','john c','Heading 12';


WITH CTE_Heading
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT custHeading
    FROM #Test
),
CTE_Paired_Headings
AS
(
    SELECT  A.custHeading AS Head1,
            B.CustHeading AS Head2
    FROM CTE_Heading A
    INNER JOIN CTE_Heading B
    ON A.custHeading < B.custHeading
),
CTE_Matching_Cust
AS
(
SELECT  A.Head1,
        A.Head2,
        B.CustId,
        B.CustName
FROM CTE_Paired_Headings A
INNER JOIN #Test B
    ON A.Head1 = B.CustHeading
    OR A.Head2 = B.CustHeading
GROUP BY A.Head1,A.Head2,B.CustId,B.CustName
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
),
CTE_HeadingGroups
AS
(
SELECT  'M' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Head1,Head2) AS VARCHAR(5)) MatchingID,
        Head1,
        Head2
FROM CTE_Matching_Cust
GROUP BY Head1,Head2
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
)

SELECT  B.CustId,
        B.CustName,
        A.MatchingID
FROM CTE_HeadingGroups A
INNER JOIN CTE_Matching_Cust B
ON  A.Head1 = B.Head1
    AND A.Head2 = B.Head2
ORDER BY 3,1


DROP TABLE #Test
```

Results:

```
CustId      CustName                 MatchingID
-----------------------------------------------
1           john carroll             M1
2           john c                   M1
7           john c ln                M1
2           john c                   M2
5           john c lynch             M2
2           john c                   M3
6           john c l                 M3
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it nearly matching to my required output.

Comment: I fixed it. The results match up perfectly now. It was a greater than sign that should have been a less than sign.